# Open and read multiple files sequentially on linux systems

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I have a file named `file.txt`, that contains other file paths as a content. Now, am trying to open my "`file.txt`", read each `line` and load each content in the captured line, as my line is a file path. see below what my `file.txt` contains:

**file.txt:** contains

```
/Desktop/path1.txt
/Desktop/path2.txt
```

and,

**/Desktop/path1.txt**:contains

```
something...is here in this line
do you have you iurgiuwegrirg
ewirgewyrwyier
jhwegruyergue
```

**/Desktop/path2.txt**:contains contents like..

```
abcd
efg
jshdjsdd
```

Then finally,as explained above, i want to:

```
1.open file.txt
2.read each line, here line is a path
3.open line as a path,(/Desktop/path1.txt ...and /Desktop/path2.txt)
4.read contents in each path.
```

take a look at my work:

**main.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PATH "file.txt"

void load_data_path(char *data_path)
{
   FILE *stream;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;

   stream = fopen(data_path, "r");
   if (stream == NULL)
   {
       printf("FILE..not found\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) 
   {
       printf("Content in path: %s", line);
   }
   free(line);
   fclose(stream);
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
void load_parent_path(char *init_path)
{
   FILE *stream;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;

   stream = fopen(init_path, "r");
   if (stream == NULL)
   {
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) 
   {
       printf("Current path from parent file: %s\n", line);
       //pass a current line, a path to another reader function
       load_data_path(line);
   }
   free(line);
   fclose(stream);
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(void)
{
   //PATH="file.txt", this functions reads contents of file.txt
   load_parent_path(PATH);
}
```

the problem is, when i run my main.cpp, it says `FILE...not found`, from `void load_data_path(char *data_path)` function. and `segfault` when i remove `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`

Any suggestion? thanks.

Comment: you remove newline from file-path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getline() reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of
>          the buffer containing the text into *lineptr.  The buffer is null-
>          terminated **and includes the newline character**, if one was found.

You can remove the trailing newline using:

```
char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
if (p != NULL) *p = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remind that the function `getline()` does not remove the newline character. When the `load_parent_path` function calls `load_data_path` it therefore passes a filename that includes the newline.

Comment: You mean `does not remove the newline character` instead of `end-of-line`, edited